# Finding a closed form of following summation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

**Question:** Can anyone help to find closed form of following summation:
$\sum_{i=0}^{20}(-1)^i\times\binom{n}{i}\times \binom{n}{n-i}$ ?

I think this problem have a raltion with $\sum_{i=0}^{20}(-1)^i\times\binom{n}{i}$ ,but i can't prove this claim.

Comment: So,give me a hint to solve this problem.thanks

Comment: Note that $n$ choose $i$ is the same as $n$ choose $(n-i)$.

Comment: $n=20 $ or not? Can you try smaller $n$'s and see if you can find a pattern?

Comment: n most be $\geq 20$